# Can I restrict a property decorator could only be applied to limited types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to make a decorator only works on string properties and generate error if not. Is that possible?

```
function deco () {
  // How can I make the restrictions here?
  return function (target:any, key:string) {
  }
}

class A {
  @deco() // This should be valid
  foo:string

  @deco() // This should be invalid
  bar:number
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Allowed<T, K extends keyof T, Allow> =
    T[K] extends Allow // If T extends Allow
        ? T            // 'return' T
        : never;       // else 'return' never

function deco () {
    return function <
        T, // infers typeof target    
        K extends keyof T // infers typeof target's key
    >(
        target: Allowed<T, K, string>, // only allow when T[K] is string 
        key: K
    ) { }
}

class A {
  @deco() // This should be valid
  foo!: string

  @deco() // This should be invalid
  bar!: number
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwDwBUA0UDSUEAHsBAHZoDOUA1hCIgGZS6wIoB8UAvAFBRBrANr4AukVIVq7JMigB6BVACSLLJLKUa8OQKEGA-KwOmhSqAHIAThGABXa+Uut9ZgFxRyEAG4RrANxmisoQcFTQNnaOzl6+-nx8TPbkAMbAAJaI5FBoEKmIUAAUAJRQAN5uULYOTlDJaZnZUBhVBmwWGeRM-jSgkMxQwACG1gDmdgZtQoQkWjL0jOohUF091n3gEIMj43aWNItVnEXTgrsTwJ66KOjYePh4VMDWXWOceBbZcCBQwxzyZAACwoInEqxoz1e5DGUDOdAYnnwVTK5SgAF8+Ji+Kk4MMqDoKvoAAJ5AqlFZYIEZSFAxD2OBoKAAI2gPn+GTQ+iYiEQAEJPFC3olBKT8ogKRYqTSoFQ6QymazVuR2XBOfpmaMBV57ABbVnWLF8IA)